# Взять и записать данные в таблицу cvs

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, таблицы

У меня есть файл `1.txt`, содержащий текст следующего формата:

```
> Действие
Результат действия 
с 
разными переносами
> И еще одно действие
И еще раз
> И ещё...
```

И так весь файл. Файл большой (40 мб). Мне необходимо записать данные в таблицу cvs следующего формата:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это можно сделать на Python???

Answer (score 2):

Что именно у вас не получается? Попробуйте декомпозировать задачу для начала. Составить план действий:

1. открыть файл на чтение
2. читать файл построчно
3. при появлении знака `>` в начале строки добавить эту строку в список действий
4. а следующие строки, пока не появится опять символ `>` добавить в другой список - результатов
5. создать, например, `Pandas DataFrame` на основе собранных списков дайствий и результатов
6. записать `DataFrame` в `csv` файл

После этого берёте составленный план действий - и кодируете. И вот когда вы всё это сделали у вас что-то не получается, код не работает как надо и вы не знаете, что делать дальше - тогда задаёте вопрос и вам помогают его решить.